# Issue in connecting to Hadoop with Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver

Tags: hadoop, ssl, hive, cloudera

The Error is :

> [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (5) Error occurred while contacting server: Could not refill buffer. This could be because you are trying to establish a non-SSL connection to a SSL-enabled server.

And while trying to connect with SSL Enabled.
It is Showing the following

> [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (6) Error occurred while contacting server: SSL_connect: error code: 0. This could be because you are trying to establish a SSL connection to a server that does not have SSL enabled.

Comment: Their driver is compatible with HDInsights and I see that you have tagged cloudera in the question. Why not use Cloudera's JDBC driver instead?

Comment: okay I thought it is compatible with Cloudera but it seems it is not connecting. I will try with Cloudera ODBC. Thank you

Comment: Details here:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40886

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion, go to cloudera, download the Cloudera ODBC. For me it solved the issue. Of course - there is still an open question, to understand what's the issue with Microsoft one.